# How to grant group access to a singularity instance

Tags: group, singularity

I constructed a singularity/apptainer sif container and I can now start an instance of this container. Is there a way to grant other users (in a group) the right to run the instance ?

In short, How can I makes things such that any user in the group users is able to do `singularity run instance:\\myinstance`